# Debugging web service with Intellij

Tags: java, web-services, debugging, intellij-idea

I work with a web service (SOAP) that is installed on a remote server (Websphere). Since I do not fully understand its operation, I would like to use debugging to understand the code step by step. I want to use the local instance Intellij (ultimate). My problem is that due to little experience I do not know how to do it. I have questions:

- to check the operation of WS I want to send queries to the server using SOAPUI. Is there a possibility for me to look at Intellij (using breakpoints) what values are returned at a given stage?
- how to connect it all together?
- is there a different, better way to check the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that debug is enabled on your remote server. This can probably be configured in Websphere. Then, in IntelliJ select the "run configurations" dropdown and "Edit Configurations". Hit the "+" and select remote. Set the correct host and port, and click "OK". Then, start the run configuration in debug mode, add some breakpoints and debug away!